# Build Succeeds, But have heap corupted. Using 2-D Arrays

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, 2d, heap-memory

I've created a 2-D Array, but fails and I get "Unhandled exception at 0x77a415de in lab10.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted." Not sure where to go from here or how to debug. I believe it has something to do with the size of my arrays or using malloc(). Thank you so much for the help in advance!

```
//Get the number of Columns from the user
printf("Enter the number of rows and columns:\n");
scanf("%d", &dimension);

//Allocate 1-D Array of Pointers, Array 'a'
a = (int** ) malloc( sizeof(int)*dimension);
if(a == NULL)
{
    printf("\nError Allocating Memory");
    exit(1);
}

//Allocate Rows for 2-D Array; Array 'a'
for(r = 0; r < dimension; r++)
{
    a[r] = (int*) malloc( sizeof(int) * dimension);
    if (a[r] == NULL)
    {
        for(i = 0; i< r; i++)
            free(a[i]);
        printf("\nError Allocating Memory");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

There is more, but I do this 4 different times from the same integer 'dimension'. Thank you!

Comment: i think you should add 'c' as a tag for your question

Comment: I don't see anything particularly wrong with your allocations. It seems more likely something is overrunning one or more of the arrays at another point - you might need to show some of how you use those arrays once you have them allocated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take a time and i compile your first example and it runs fine, i thing that the error then could be that `a` must be of type `int **a`. Also i have to add the types to `r` and `i` variables. If this dosen't works, then i think that you must specify the line of the error, and also add the variables declarations, and the `#includes`. Hope this could helps...

Comment: I applied your suggested changes, but it appears I get the same fault! I do see what you're saying though!

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

```
a = (int** ) malloc( sizeof(int)*dimension);
```

You're allocating enough space for an array of `dimension` elements of type `int`, but then you're using it as an array of `int*`.  If you're compiling a 64-bit program, then `sizeof(int*)` is 8 but `sizeof(int)` is 4, so you're not allocating enough space.  You need to use `sizeof(int*)`:

```
a = (int** ) malloc( sizeof(int*)*dimension);
//                          ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

In the snippet

```
//Allocate 1-D Array of Pointers, Array 'a'
a = (int** ) malloc( sizeof(int)*dimension);
```

the comment does not match the actual code. In the code, you are allocating room for `dimension` integers, not pointers.

As a pointer is likely larger than an int, the loop allocating the rows goes outside the allocated memory.

The initial allocation should read

```
a = malloc( sizeof(int*)*dimension);
```

or

```
a = malloc( dimension * sizeof *a);
```

The second form has the advantage that it is always correct for allocating any array of size `dimension`.

Answer (score 2):

First:

```
a = (int** ) malloc( sizeof(int)*dimension);
```

You are allocating array of pointers and therefore you want:

```
a = (int** ) malloc( sizeof(int*)*dimension);
```

The size of int and int* is not guaranteed to be the same!

Second:

```
if (a[r] == NULL)
{
    for(i = 0; i< r; i++)
        free(a[i]);
    printf("\nError Allocating Memory");
    exit(1);
}
```

You free memory of all rows, but you don't free memory of "a" itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my error! It was an infinite for loop that was located in one of my other 'for' loops! Also, as stated by many people above, I should have been multipling by (int*) not just (int)! Thank you so much!